# RNAfold Time complexity In VinnaRNA Package

Tags: c++, time-complexity, bioinformatics, software-design, dna-sequence

Can anyone tell me what is the complexity of `RNAfold` algorithm In `VinnaRNA` Package. 
https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/

This Algo. is present in `ViennaRNA-2.4.4\ViennaRNA-2.4.4\src\bin` .
Help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an empirical runtime analysis in the link you provided. You can see a linear computation time on a log/log diagram.

This means you can write (using `log` for logarithm in base 10 and calling `T` the time complexity of the algorithm)

```
   log(T(10^n)) = a.n + b                          for a and b to be read from the graph
=> T(10^n) = 10^(a.n + b) = C.10^(a.n)             with C constant
=> T(n) = T(10^(log(n)) = C.10^(a.log(n)) = C.n^a
```

Now, reading the graph, you can see that

- `T(length of RNA sequence = 1000) ~= 10^0 = 1`
- `T(10000) ~= 10^2.6`

Which would give you an approximation of `a ~= 2.6`
If you want to be conservative, you can bound `a` with `3` which results in complexity

```
T(n) = O(n^3)
```

Where `n` is the length of RNA sequence in nucleotides.